How do I insert a table name into a mysql query with ExpressJs?
I'm trying to use this to get contents of a specific table:
let tablename = req.body.login
connection.query('SELECT * FROM ?', tablename, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) throw err
    res.send(rows)
})

But due to tablename being a string, it gets inserted into the query with quotes, resulting in an error. If this can't work, how can I structure my database to be able to add users and more data to any chosen one?

Use ?? instead of ?. This is used for substituting table and column names rather than values.

Using a raw SQL query, you can add the table name previous to the call of the query method, something like this:
let tablename = req.body.login;
let rawQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tablename;
connection.query(rawQuery, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) throw err
    res.send(rows)
})

hope this helps.

You can just use template literal
using  `
let tablename = req.body.login
connection.query(`SELECT * FROM ${tablename}`, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) throw err
    res.send(rows)
})

or simplifying more
connection.query(`SELECT * FROM ${req.body.login}`, (err, rows) => {
    if (err) throw err
    res.send(rows)
})

